# Is DotNetActivity still available on ADF V2?

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

Recently project changed ADF version from v1 to v2.
The pipeline, from legacy workpiece, contains dotnetactivity that runs on v1.(w/IDoNetActivity Interface inhered to class)

I was searching if dotnetactivity still available on v2.
But official adf v2 documents does not seem to have dotnetactivity on activity list instead customactivity with console app.

If no, i may need to modify all dotnetactivity and complete corresponding test again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DonNetActivity has been replaced by the Custom Activity in V2, as it has flexibility to run any command which is not limited to DotNet code. If you have a lot of projects which depends on the V1 interface, you might want to implement your own wrapper executable which converts V2 input (JSON files) to V1 interface. A migration tool is also considered in backlog of V2 GA, but no commitment yet.

Comment: Thank you for knowledge and possible solution, adoption from V1 .netactivity to v2 customactivity.